# How to make an entire background image to fit different size computer screens?

Tags: html, css

I need to let the image full of the entire browser,but the image's width and height pixel is fixed.How to make it fix different size of screens.Can i make the background image stretch using css?

Comment: use background-size: cover;

Comment: 2 options, c-link already told you one, other is `background-size: 100% 100%`, where first `100%` - `X` and 2nd `100%` - `Y`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with:

```
background-size: 100%;
```

If you want to control the height and width, you can do it like this:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

However, not all browsers have implemented this feature yet.

Comment: see http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/ for further usage examples and browser support.